# php issues returning an array from a function

Tags: php

I'm pulling information through curl from Fedex Rate Quote Sytem.  I am getting the necessary information.  The curl functions correctly.  The results are accurate.  **But, when I try to add the results to an array, it wont pass them from the function to the page.  Its like the results arent being stored in the function.**

```
foreach($result->SOAPENVBody->RateReply->RateReplyDetails as $value) {
    $number = ++$number;
    $key1 = $result->SOAPENVBody->RateReply->RateReplyDetails[$number]->ServiceType;
    $value1 = $result->SOAPENVBody->RateReply->RateReplyDetails[$number]->RatedShipmentDetails[0]->ShipmentRateDetail->TotalNetCharge->Amount;


    $options[$key1] = $value1;
}

    return $options;
```

**I know that the function WILL pass the array set up like this as I tested it with**

```
$key1 = '1';
$value1 = 'Hello';
```

**It passed that information to the page.**

When I echo out the curl results through $key1 and $value1 (`echo $key1 . $value1;`) it displays the correct information on the page as well.  IT just wont pass it through to the array.

Below I am pasting the results from the echo to show what information is being retrieved

```
FIRST_OVERNIGHT: 194.35
PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT: 147.83
STANDARD_OVERNIGHT: 133.77
FEDEX_2_DAY_AM: 111.54
FEDEX_2_DAY: 99.78
FEDEX_EXPRESS_SAVER: 89.71
FEDEX_GROUND: 20.92
```

And I'm figuring someone will want to see how I am calling the function...here it is from the main page where the function is being called.

```
include_once('inc/functions/fedex_rate.php');
          $fedex_options = array();
         $fedex_options = fedex_rate($totalweight);

          foreach ($fedex_options as $key => $value) {
              echo '<tr><td colspan="2"><div class="margin10">'. $key .'</div></td><td colspan="2"><div class="margin10">'. $value .'</div></td></tr>'; 
          }
```

I even tried just using `$options` as well in the foreach loop on the main page; however, that didnt work either.  I finally saw an example where someone set up a new array using array details from the function and so that is where I stopped.

---

Below is the fedex rate quote complete function minus sensitive information

```
<?

function getProperty($var) {
if ($var == 'key') return 'xxxxxxxxx';
if ($var == 'password') return 'xxxxxxxxx';
if ($var == 'account') return 'xxxxxx';
if ($var == 'meter') return 'xxxxx';
}


function fedex_rate($totalweight) {
//your account details here
$key = getProperty('key');
$password = getProperty('password');;
$account_number = getProperty('account');
$meter_number = getProperty('meter');
$residential = '1'; // 1 = true, 0 = false
    if ($residential == 1) { $residential = 'true'; }
    if ($residential == 0) { $residential = 'false'; }
if($residential == 1) { $servicetype = 'GROUND_HOME_DELIVERY'; }
if ($residential == 0) { $servicetype = ''; }



$recipient_address = 'xxxxxxx';
$recipient_city = 'xxxxxx';
$recipient_state = 'xx';
$recipient_zip = 'xxxxx';
$recipient_county = 'xx';



$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v13"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:RateRequest>
<ns1:WebAuthenticationDetail>
<ns1:UserCredential>
<ns1:Key>'.$key.'</ns1:Key>
<ns1:Password>'.$password.'</ns1:Password>
</ns1:UserCredential></ns1:WebAuthenticationDetail>
<ns1:ClientDetail>
<ns1:AccountNumber>'.$account_number.'</ns1:AccountNumber>
<ns1:MeterNumber>'.$meter_number.'</ns1:MeterNumber>
</ns1:ClientDetail>
<ns1:TransactionDetail><ns1:CustomerTransactionId> *** Rate Request v13 using PHP ***</ns1:CustomerTransactionId></ns1:TransactionDetail><ns1:Version><ns1:ServiceId>crs</ns1:ServiceId><ns1:Major>13</ns1:Major><ns1:Intermediate>0</ns1:Intermediate><ns1:Minor>0</ns1:Minor></ns1:Version><ns1:ReturnTransitAndCommit>true</ns1:ReturnTransitAndCommit>

<ns1:RequestedShipment>
<ns1:DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</ns1:DropoffType>';
// add- if service type is selected, echo service type code.  if not, leave it out
//<ns1:ServiceType>'. $service_type .'</ns1:ServiceType>
$xml .= '<ns1:PackagingType>YOUR_PACKAGING</ns1:PackagingType>
<ns1:TotalInsuredValue>
<ns1:Currency>USD</ns1:Currency>
</ns1:TotalInsuredValue>

<ns1:Shipper>
<ns1:Contact>
<ns1:PersonName>Sender Name</ns1:PersonName>
<ns1:CompanyName>Sender Company Name</ns1:CompanyName>
<ns1:PhoneNumber></ns1:PhoneNumber>
</ns1:Contact>

<ns1:Address>
<ns1:StreetLines></ns1:StreetLines>
<ns1:City></ns1:City>
<ns1:StateOrProvinceCode></ns1:StateOrProvinceCode>
<ns1:PostalCode>xxxxxx</ns1:PostalCode>
<ns1:CountryCode>xx</ns1:CountryCode>
</ns1:Address>
</ns1:Shipper>

<ns1:Recipient>
<ns1:Contact>
<ns1:PersonName>Recipient Name</ns1:PersonName>
<ns1:CompanyName>Company Name</ns1:CompanyName>
<ns1:PhoneNumber></ns1:PhoneNumber>
</ns1:Contact>

<ns1:Address>
<ns1:StreetLines>'. $recipient_address .'</ns1:StreetLines>
<ns1:City>'. $recipient_city .'</ns1:City>
<ns1:StateOrProvinceCode>'. $recipient_state .'</ns1:StateOrProvinceCode>
<ns1:PostalCode>'. $recipient_zip .'</ns1:PostalCode>
<ns1:CountryCode>'. $recipient_county .'</ns1:CountryCode>
<ns1:Residential>'. $residential .'</ns1:Residential>
</ns1:Address>
</ns1:Recipient>

<ns1:ShippingChargesPayment>
<ns1:PaymentType>SENDER</ns1:PaymentType>
<ns1:Payor>
<ns1:ResponsibleParty>
<ns1:AccountNumber>'.$account_number.'</ns1:AccountNumber>
</ns1:ResponsibleParty>
</ns1:Payor>
</ns1:ShippingChargesPayment>

<ns1:RateRequestTypes>ACCOUNT</ns1:RateRequestTypes>

<ns1:PackageCount>1</ns1:PackageCount>
<ns1:RequestedPackageLineItems>

<ns1:SequenceNumber>1</ns1:SequenceNumber>

<ns1:GroupPackageCount>1</ns1:GroupPackageCount>

<ns1:Weight>
<ns1:Units>LB</ns1:Units>
<ns1:Value>'.$totalweight.'</ns1:Value>
</ns1:Weight>

<ns1:Dimensions>
<ns1:Length>10</ns1:Length>
<ns1:Width>10</ns1:Width>
<ns1:Height>10</ns1:Height>
<ns1:Units>IN</ns1:Units>
</ns1:Dimensions>

</ns1:RequestedPackageLineItems>

</ns1:RequestedShipment>
</ns1:RateRequest>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result_xml = curl_exec($ch);

// remove colons and dashes to simplify the xml
$result_xml = str_replace(array(':','-'), '', $result_xml);
$result = @simplexml_load_string($result_xml);

;


$number = -1;

foreach($result->SOAPENVBody->RateReply->RateReplyDetails as $value) {
    $number = ++$number;
    $key1 = $result->SOAPENVBody->RateReply->RateReplyDetails[$number]->ServiceType;
    $value1 = $result->SOAPENVBody->RateReply->RateReplyDetails[$number]->RatedShipmentDetails[0]->ShipmentRateDetail->TotalNetCharge->Amount;
    //echo $key1 .': '. $value1 .'<br />';

    $options[$key1] = $value1;
}

    return $options;

} // function
```

---

---

I was able to get it to work by adding an empty value before and after the $result in the array...but WHY is this the case? Why cant I pass the value of the $result tag to the array by itself?

```
$key1 = ''. $result->SOAPENVBody->RateReply->RateReplyDetails[$number]->ServiceType .'';

    $value1 = ''. $result->SOAPENVBody->RateReply->RateReplyDetails[$number]->RatedShipmentDetails[0]->ShipmentRateDetail->TotalNetCharge->Amount .'';
```

### CAN ANYONE TELL ME WHY I cannot pass the $result directly to the array without any additional blank tags? This ended up being the problem, so the person who figures that out gets the accepted answer.

Comment: can you post the fedex_rate() complete function?

Comment: @monstercode - done.

Comment: Try initializing `$options` before you start the `foreach` and in the `foreach` just add data to it.

Comment: @ivanivan - huh? haha

Comment: I found A solution.  I posted as an unaccepted answer as well as on my question.  Can anyone tell me why $result cant be passed as a standalone value?  That ended up being the problem to the entire thing....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After parsing XML, every element is SimpleXMLElement object and **object can't be set as key in array**.

When you concat empty string, it became string instead of Object. as you know when you try to echo an object it call __toString method (if defined).

if you like to debug this issue, try to call,

```
var_dump($result->SOAPENVBody->RateReply->RateReplyDetails[$number]->ServiceType)
```

You can also resolve this by:

```
$key1 = (string)$result->SOAPENVBody->RateReply->RateReplyDetails[$number]->ServiceType;
```

OR

```
$key1 = $result->SOAPENVBody->RateReply->RateReplyDetails[$number]->ServiceType->__toString();
```

Comment: which option is the better option to use?

Comment: In my opinion, (string) is better option

Comment: thank you for the explanation.  I am new to parsing XML so that helps me for future projects working with XML.  This works perfectly.  You rock!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $options is not defined before in fedex_rate(). just define it as an empty array before the foreach.

```
 $options = array();
 foreach($result->SOAPENVBody->RateReply->RateReplyDetails as $value) {
    ....
```

Comment: that doesnt solve it.  I've had it set and it didnt work either,.  Like I said, I can set a random array results `$key1 = '1'; $value1 = 'Hello';` and it returns those as the array.  ITs something about setting the `$result` tag in the array.  ITs not wanting to pass the actual `$result` to the array even though it does allow me to echo it

Comment: is the $result->SOAPENVBody->RateReply->RateReplyDetails not null, or traversable? Maybe the foreach is not executing because of being empty.

Comment: when I echo the `$key1` and `$value1`, it returns the correct results.  It has a value set in it.  I've tested the results a bunch of times to double check for that.  You can see the data in the original question.  The key is the shipment type, the value is the price

Comment: Are you passing the correct value in $totalweight in the main script to fedex_rate()? (I suspect there is code missing between the include and the function call)

Comment: yes because if i wasnt then the echo wouldnt return the correct results.

Comment: it has soething to do with passing $result.  When I change the code to this... `$key1 = '"'. $result->SOAPENVBody->RateReply->RateReplyDetails[$number]->ServiceType .'"';
 $value1 = '"'. $result->SOAPENVBody->RateReply->RateReplyDetails[$number]->RatedShipmentDetails[0]->ShipmentRateDetail->TotalNetCharge->Amount .'"';` it passes, but it adds `"` before and after the code....need the code the pass without the `"`

Comment: I'm not sure if $result cant be passed by itself...I'm not sure.  Doesnt make sense to me as I'm just trying to pass the value of $result

Comment: got it to work...but why?  `$key1 = ''. $result->SOAPENVBody->RateReply->RateReplyDetails[$number]->ServiceType .'';
 $value1 = ''. $result->SOAPENVBody->RateReply->RateReplyDetails[$number]->RatedShipmentDetails[0]->ShipmentRateDetail->TotalNetCharge->Amount .'';`  I literally just add a blank before and after each value...why does that matter?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by adding an empty value before and after the $result in the array...**but WHY is this the case?**  Why cant I pass the value of the $result tag to the array by itself?

```
$key1 = ''. $result->SOAPENVBody->RateReply->RateReplyDetails[$number]->ServiceType .'';

    $value1 = ''. $result->SOAPENVBody->RateReply->RateReplyDetails[$number]->RatedShipmentDetails[0]->ShipmentRateDetail->TotalNetCharge->Amount .'';
```